# TaskPane in Office Add-in word document close event

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office-js, office-addins

Is there an event available in Office.js which notifies the office addin when the word/excel document closes. I want to implement a scenario where if the user closes the word document (where the taskpane addin is added) the user is shown a custom message before the word/excel document closes.

Answer (score 0):

That event is not supported in Office.js. But it's a good idea. Please go to [Office Developer suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and search for "word events". Vote up any suggestions that match your needs, or create a new suggestion.